# Making Gradient Images Quickly with C++

Tags: c++, python, image, gradient

I'm currently working with Python to create images of gradients. However, for my uses I'm afraid that Python may just be too slow. I know that Python can be extended with C++ with relative ease.

So what are some quick ways to produce images of gradients in C++?

Comment: Have you tried Python and know it to be too slow, or do you just guess that it is too slow? And besides any image manipulation you do in Python is probably subbed out to C anyways.

Comment: Yes, I definitely did it in Python (Using the Tkinter PhotoImage class). It was fast, however more speed is always nice.

Comment: Try doing it in Python using the script listed [here](http://jtauber.com/blog/2008/05/18/creating_gradients_programmatically_in_python/) which creates .png files. The embedded link to the .py file is dead, but I found the last version of it using the WayBackMachine [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100612051705/http://jtauber.com/blog/2008/05/18/creating_gradients_programmatically_in_python/).

Answer (score 2):

Writing a bitmap manually is quite easy. For a Windows Bitmap you need a 54 byte header and then an array of colour values. ([.bmp file specs](http://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/spec/e27073c25463436f8a64fa789c886d9c/view.htm))

So, create a file, write the header, supply the pixel array. For a gradient generating the colour values should be fairly simple.

.pgm/.ppm files are even easier as they have much simpler headers.

Comment: You can also use a variety of image libraries, such as DevIL, for writing the image. The hardest part is filling in the data, which is just a gradient formula (typically lerp).

Comment: @Benjamin Although a rough overview may not be exactly what was wanted, just asking for (or supplying) the details would have been more constructive.

Comment: @sheepez: You're right.  I've retracted my comment, it was inappropriate.  But your answer could use quite a bit more detail.

Comment: @Benjamin It's a fair criticism, I did rush that answer. If I get the time I will add some code, the .bmp stuff can take a little while to get your head around but the .ppm stuff is fairly self explanatory.